# im getting this error on from that The tag <from> is unrecognized in this browser

Tags: reactjs

ERORR=>{
Warning: The tag  is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
}

CODE=>{
}

```
        <input type="text" name="lastName" onChange={handleValues} placeholder="Last Name" value={Inputdata.lastName} />

        <input type="email" name="email" onChange={handleValues} placeholder="Email" value={Inputdata.email} />

        <textarea value={Inputdata.textarea} onChange={handleValues} name="textarea" placeholder="Massage...." />
```

{/*

```
        <input type="radio" name="isAllow" checked={Inputdata.isAllow == "Allowed"}  onChange={handleValues} value="Allowed" />Allow

        <input type="radio" name="isAllow" checked={Inputdata.isAllow == "Dont Allow"} value="Dont Allow" onChange={handleValues} />Dont Allow */}

            <select value={Inputdata.cityName} onChange={handleValues} name="cityName">
            <option value="">---choose city</option>
            <option value="hyderbad">hyderbad</option>
            <option value="karachi">karachi</option>
            <option value="islamabad">islamabad</option>
            <option value="lahore">lahore</option>
            <option value="mirpur">mirpur</option>
        </select>
        </from>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the tag you mean is `<form>` not `<from>`